# How do I hide something when a validation runs in Laravel Blade using Livewire?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have an input type of file in my Laravel blade, I also have validation of `image|max:1024` in the livewire. The problem is the input validates but it errors me out because the Laravel Blade displays the `img` that is not a file type of image so I want to hide it when it doesn't reach the validation.

```html
    <div class="pb-2">
        @if ($header_image)
            @error('header_image')
                <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
            @enderror
            <img src="{{ $header_image->temporaryUrl() }}" height="30%" width='50%'>
        @else
            <img src="{{url('storage/photos/'.$banner->header_image)}}" height="30%" width='50%' />
        @endif
    </div>
```

I want to hide the one with the `temporaryUrl()`.

Comment: what exactly you want to hide, the input element or the error bag???

Comment: I want to hide the img element. Which is the one that errors me out when i input a file that is not an image

Comment: then if error is thrown make null that property, that way on blade @if statement don't get reached into the ->temporaryUrl()

Comment: Can I have a reference on how to make this null?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this validator approach to to any action on fails

```
$validation = Validator::make($data,$rules);
if($validation->fails()) {
   $this->property = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach to this. I use livewire `dehydrate` function. In livewire component:

```
public function dehydrate()
{
    if ($this->getErrorBag()) {
        //Do whatever you like..
    }
}
```